# Groovy: DOM document in bytes

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I have script:

```
import groovy.xml.*
String  xml = "<xml><el>value</el><el>value</el></xml>"
     def reader = new StringReader(xml)
def doc = DOMBuilder.parse(reader)
def records = doc.documentElement
```

Now I need put records in stream in bytes. How I can do it? I try records.toString().toBytes(), but .toString() not supported `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl`

Comment: What do you mean "_put records in stream in bytes_"...  Just the text of the xml?

Comment: Yes, I need xml put xml text in stream